# What does string.indexOf("*.") do in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm debugging some code and have found the following code snippet and just don't get what it does:

```
function appendModelPrefix(value, prefix) {
    if (value.indexOf("*.") === 0) {
        value = value.replace("*.", prefix);
    }
    return value;
}
```

What does my value string has to look like to get validated by the if-condition? 
And to what does "*." exactly do? I don't get the wildcard...

Comment: I could be wrong but i think its checking the value and if nothing appears before the "." than it fills it in with a prefix

Comment: This should help you understand what the code does: http://jsfiddle.net/fuAwb/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doesn't wildcard. It searches for and then replaces a literal `"*."` by `prefix`

`indexOf` finds the first occurence of `"*."` in the string:

```
>>>"aaa*.".indexOf("*.")
3
```

So your consition will succeed if the string starts with a "*." (index 0)

```
>>> "*.aaa".indexOf("*.")
0
```

The replace method will then replace this first occurence of "*." with the chosen prefix

```
>>> "*.*.".replace("*.", "z")
"z*."
```

---

BTW, you only get wildcard replacements if you use regexes instead of string patterns:

```
>>> 'abbbc'.replace(/b+/, 'z')
"azc"
```

Comment: Note that it does this only if `value` starts with `*.` (i.e. `=== 0`)

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much, you just saved my evening! ;D

Answer (score 2):

indexOf will give the position of the text inside the string.

So the if statement reads if `value` starts with "*." then replace it with `prefix`

Answer (score 2):

If the string starts with the substring `*.`, then replace it with `prefix`.

```
>>> "*.".indexOf('*.')
0
>>> "a*.".indexOf('*.')
1
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `value` starts with `*.`, then it replaces the `*.` by the `prefix` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There is no wilcard-thing in javascript `.indexOf()`.

It simply is replacing the value `*.` by `prefix`.

Answer (score 0):

Its a vanilla string match, if `value` begins with `*.` then the `*.` is replaced by the string in `prefix`

```
"aaa" -> "aaa"
"*.a" -> "a" + prefix
```